# Использование множества C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос.

Когда я вставляют элемент в множество/мультимножетсво

```
example.insert(make_pair(3,4));
```

Могу ли я как нибудь сразу узнать на какое место он стал, не делая такого

```
exampla.find(make_pair(3,4));
```

Цель этого конечно же экономия K*log N времени, которое может потратится для поиска K элементов после их вставления.

Думаю цель и вопрос понятны

Answer (score 3):

Но ведь `set::insert()` возвращает флаг, выполнена ли вставка, и итератор, указывающий на место, куда вставлен этот элемент...

См. описание [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Для `multiset`, где может быть много одинаковых энтов, возвращается просто итератор, указывающий на вставленный элемент.

См. описание [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert).